# Using a for loop in python with more than 1 variable

Tags: python

I am writing a program in which I want to use 3 variables in my `for` loop and every variable should run from a different start index. Here is a snippet from my code. I have a table named codons in which I have some value for every three letter for e.g `'atg':'F'`, `'ggg':'Q'` , `'ttg':'E'` etc

```
seq='atgggggggcccccc'
seqlen= len(seq)
aaseq1=[]
aaseq2=[]
aaseq3=[]
for i in range(0,seqlen,3):
     codon1 = seq[i:i+3]
     aa1 = codons[codon1]
     aaseq1.append(aa1)  
print ''.join(aaseq1)
```

In this code, I am running variable `i` from position 0 but I want to use 2 more variables (`j` and `k`) which will run from 1 and 2 respectively and append the result in `aaseq2` and `aaseq3` list.

```
 codon2 = seq[j:j+3]
 codon3 = seq[k:k+3]
```

Comment: Could you not simply use `i+1` and `i+2` with some `if` statements to prevent out of bounds?

Comment: but with which variable I will compare the if statement.. I am unable to do like this

Comment: can I use a variable at the place of 0 in for loop and then I can compare using if statement ?

Comment: Why can't you use 3 separate loops?  i, j, and k don't seem to be related to one another?

Comment: From your description, it’s unclear what the job of `j` and `k` is and what makes them different to `i`. Can you show a concrete example, for example using that sequence you have in the question? What should happen exactly?

Comment: Can we assume that `len(seq)` will _always_ be a multiple of 3? BTW, your `aaseq1`, `aaseq2`, `aaseq3`, are _lists_ not dictionaries. But it looks like `codons` is a dictionary, with the codon triplet strings as the keys and the amino acid codes as the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to do this and the best one to use depends on how big your `seq` is in real life.  The other answers give some nice ways to utilise Python features to avoid building lists explictly.

I'll give you one solution that goes through every group of three consecutive letters, but assigns them to one of three arrays depending on whether `i%3` is `0`,`1` or `2`.

For the example you've given - to me this is very easy to read but retains roughly the data structure you began with and I assume are familiar with.  I've taken the liberty of adding a truncated `dict` for `codons` so that the code runs.

```
codons = {'atg':'Methionine','tgg':'Tryptophan','ggg':'Glycine',
          'ggc':'Glycine','gcc':'Alanine','ccc':'Proline'}

seq='atgggggggcccccc'
seqlen= len(seq)
aaseq=[[],[],[]]

for i in range(seqlen-2):
     codon = seq[i:i+3]    
     aa = codons[codon]
     aaseq[i%3].append(aa)  

print 'aaseq1 ='
print ''.join(aaseq[0])  
print 'aaseq2 ='
print ''.join(aaseq[1])  
print 'aaseq3 ='
print ''.join(aaseq[2])
```

This gives the output:

```
aaseq1 =
MethionineGlycineGlycineProlineProline
aaseq2 =
TryptophanGlycineGlycineProline
aaseq3 =
GlycineGlycineAlanineProline
```

If you want a more concise form - try this:

```
#Make every codon by zipping the sequence offset by one each time
codon_sequence = [''.join(z) for z in zip(seq,seq[1:],seq[2:])]
#Print every 3rd codon - starting at zero...
print 'aaseq1 = ',''.join([codons[c] for c in codon_sequence[::3]])
#...then starting at 1...
print 'aaseq2 = ',''.join([codons[c] for c in codon_sequence[1::3]])
#...you get the picture...
print 'aaseq3 = ',''.join([codons[c] for c in codon_sequence[2::3]])
```

Of course - rather than printing the sequences as the last step, you can assign them to variables if you need to do further processing.

Comment: The first two should have one more Proline on the end. Now you have gone and grown antlers or a third ear!. Biology is sooooo picky.

Comment: @uhoh. Yes - you're right.  Thanks.  Hmm - my `-3` should be `-2`.  I think it's only the first one actually... Unless a `cc` on it's own should also resolve to `Proline`.  My Biology is as good as you'd expect from an electronic engineer...

Comment: ...but +1  I like your methods + explanation! (and your right, just the first one). That's the gift that `zip` gives, it manages the stragglers so you don't have to think about it and double check.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be looking for the built-in `zip` function, which allows for lock-step iteration. Combined with tuple unpacking, it works like this:

```
>>> for i,j in zip(range(3), range(10,13)):
...   print(i,j)
... 
0 10
1 11
2 12
```

The arguments to `zip` are anything you can normally use in that part of the `for` loop, and you can have any number of them (as long as you assign to the same number of variables, or to only one variable which will be a tuple at each iteration).

Answer (score 2):

(I usually) Try not to use loops in Python. While (as @PM-2ring points out in a comment) list expressions are not necessarily any faster than explicit loops, some find that they can write, understand, and debug a lot faster by letting python handle the details of iterating over data as much as possible.

Below are a few version of your program, ultimately "pythonified" down to four lines, just to see where it went.

Usually there are ways to let Python do things for you, using indexing and list expressions. These can be concise and powerful things, and many python functions just do what you would want them to. For example, zip just drops the dangling base pairs at the end without complaining.

The print statements are there just to see what's happening, of course delete them later.

```
seq='atgggggggcccccc'

s1 = seq[0::3]  # you can drop the zero, it's just for readability
s2 = seq[1::3]
s3 = seq[2::3]

c1 = zip( s1,    s2,     s3     )
c2 = zip( s2,    s3,     s1[1:] )  # frame shift of 1
c3 = zip( s3,    s1[1:], s2[1:] )  # frame shift of 2

print c1
print c2
print c3

co1 = [bp1+bp2+bp3 for (bp1, bp2, bp3) in c1]
co2 = [bp1+bp2+bp3 for (bp1, bp2, bp3) in c2]
co3 = [bp1+bp2+bp3 for (bp1, bp2, bp3) in c3]

print co1
print co2
print co3

aaseq1 = [codons(thing) for thing in c1]
aaseq2 = [codons(thing) for thing in c2]
aaseq3 = [codons(thing) for thing in c3]
```

...which could also be written like this:

```
s1, s2, s3 = [seq[i::3] for i in range(3)]   # use list comprehension and unpacking

c1 = zip( s1,    s2,     s3     )
c2 = zip( s2,    s3,     s1[1:] )  # frame shift of 1
c3 = zip( s3,    s1[1:], s2[1:] )  # frame shift of 2

co1, co2, co3 = [[tr[0]+tr[1]+tr[2] for tr in c] for c in [c1,c2,c3]]

aaseq1, asseq2, asseq3 = [[codons(trip) for trip in co] for co in [co1, co2, co3]]
```

That was just to advertise more python. For beginners it may be less readable.

This is a further pythonification (just to see where this goes...):

```
S = [seq[i::3] for i in range(3)]   # three reading frames

C = zip(S[0], S[1], S[2]), zip(S[1], S[2], S[0][1:]), zip(S[2], S[0][1:], S[1][1:]) # group

CO = [[''.join(tr) for tr in c] for c in C]    # tuples to triplet strings

AASEQs = [[codons(trip) for trip in co] for co in CO]  # look up Amino Acids
```

and finally, if you want to change the three AA sequences into just three long strings:

```
final_AASEQs = [''.join(AASEQ) for AASEQ in AASEQs]
```

Just for fun, here is what the dictionary `codons` might look like (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_codon_table), note upper case for A, T, G, C bases. So in the question `seq  = 'ATGGGGGGGCCCCCC'`

```
codons = {'CTT': 'Leu', 'ATG': 'Met', 'AAG': 'Lys', 'AAA': 'Lys', 'ATC': 'Ile',
          'AAC': 'Asn', 'ATA': 'Ile', 'AGG': 'Arg', 'CCT': 'Pro', 'ACT': 'Thr',
          'AGC': 'Ser', 'ACA': 'Thr', 'AGA': 'Arg', 'CAT': 'His', 'AAT': 'Asn',
          'ATT': 'Ile', 'CTG': 'Leu', 'CTA': 'Leu', 'CTC': 'Leu', 'CAC': 'His',
          'ACG': 'Thr', 'CAA': 'Gln', 'AGT': 'Ser', 'CAG': 'Gln', 'CCG': 'Pro',
          'CCC': 'Pro', 'TAT': 'Tyr', 'GGT': 'Gly', 'TGT': 'Cys', 'CGA': 'Arg',
          'CCA': 'Pro', 'CGC': 'Arg', 'GAT': 'Asp', 'CGG': 'Arg', 'TTT': 'Phe',
          'TGC': 'Cys', 'GGG': 'Gly', 'TAG': 'STOP', 'GGA': 'Gly', 'TGG': 'Trp',
          'GGC': 'Gly', 'TAC': 'Tyr', 'GAG': 'Glu', 'TCG': 'Ser', 'TTA': 'Leu',
          'GAC': 'Asp', 'CGT': 'Arg', 'GAA': 'Glu', 'TCA': 'Ser', 'GCA': 'Ala',
          'GTA': 'Val', 'GCC': 'Ala', 'GTC': 'Val', 'GCG': 'Ala', 'GTG': 'Val',
          'TTC': 'Phe', 'GTT': 'Val', 'GCT': 'Ala', 'ACC': 'Thr', 'TGA': 'STOP',
          'TTG': 'Leu', 'TCC': 'Ser', 'TAA': 'STOP', 'TCT': 'Ser'}  # ATG also START
```

Comment: *“Try not to use loops in Python.”* – Eh? Creating lots of intermediary lists in-memory is a lot worse than having a simple loop that does what you want in a single iteration.

Comment: That's what memory is for! :) Anyway, once you learn some python, and have a working program, you can learn to pass your million base pair data as smaller chunks, say 10 to 50 kbp at a time, so everything fits into cache. In any event, I think explicit looping over individual base pairs would never be the fastest way.

Comment: It of course depends a lot on your use cases but blindly saying to avoid loops altogether is just wrong. There are many situations where list comprehensions simply are a bad idea (readability is also a big concern here), and many things that simply cannot be done with list comprehensions. And in your example, a simple for loop that does the job in a rather naive but readable way is about 30 percent faster than your solution.

Comment: I like my original wording *"Try not to use loops in Python."* better than your paraphrase. If you have a "simple for loop" that works correctly, is faster, and is actually "simple", then it should be posted as an answer.

Comment: ...and then translated back to C where it belongs. It always goes back to the reasons why we choose to use Python in the first place.

Comment: I love list comprehensions, but they aren't magic. A `for` loop in a list comp is still a plain old Python `for` loop, it doesn't run at C speed. The list-building process itself _is_ certainly faster than an explicit `for` loop using `append` because a list comp uses a dedicated LIST_APPEND bytecode, so it avoids the overhead of a method call (and method lookup, unless the `append` method has been cached).

Comment: (cont) Sure, use a list comp when it's appropriate, but don't try to shoe-horn all list processing into list comps (or generator expressions): if it takes fancy gymnastics to write the code as a list comp / gen exp, it's probably better to use explicit looping. Also, readability counts: an explicit loop that's a few percent slower than a list comp may be preferable if the list comp code is twice as hard to read. For further thoughts on these matters, please see [Efficiency of list comprehensions](http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/04/efficiency-of-list-comprehensions).

Comment: I've edited the wording. Now I would like to see **an answer to the question here** that uses explicit loops. I'm going to continue to try to avoid reaching for the `for` loop first, and instead pause, and see how the problem can be cast with the handy tools Python gives us.

Comment: @uhoh I haven’t posted an answer because OP [still hasn’t made clear what they are asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899750/using-for-loop-in-python-with-more-than-1-variable/32902182#comment53633087_32899750). Your whole answer is completely build on what you think OP wants to do. Earlier, when I was referrring to the simple loop, I wrote [this](http://pastebin.com/T4DBxFxN) that does exactly what your code did then.

Comment: @poke I think it still does the same thing. I think you should post it! I've added a `codons` dictionary to the end of my answer. (note it uses UPPER case). If you make some random sequences of A, T, G, C with lengths of 1E+03, 1E+04 and 1E+05 and maybe 1E+06, you could do a great speed comparison.

Comment: @PM2Ring I've learned a bit more about SO and SE and Python since 2015 ;-) I've just re-discovered this post and found your comments. It turns out I still reflexively try to cram everything into list comprehensions, so your comments are as germane to day as they were when first posted!